# AG-Grid Column Headers stacked to left

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid react and when rendering table. I am getting column headers stacked to left.

The CSS provided are:

```js
<div style={{ width: '100%', height: "100vh", marginTop: '5%'}}>
                <div           
                    style={{
                    boxSizing: "border-box",
                    height: "100vh",
                    width: "100%"
                }}
                className="ag-theme-fresh"
                >
                    <AgGridReact
                        id="myGrid"
                        columnDefs={this.columnDef}
                        defaultColDef={this.defaultColDef}
                        onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
                    />
                    
                </div>
</div>
```

The table looks like:
[Ag-grid column header stacked to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRau4.png)

Comment: Thanks for posting! Currently the same in ag-grid-angular on version ag-grid 16.0.1 with ag-grid-angular 16.0.0. I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @Andrew Lobban Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: I’m working to figure that issue out myself. Planning on creating a simple app with ag-grid following the documentation.

Comment: I think the class **ag-theme-fresh** should be added as an attribute of your <AgGridReact> element.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out for my Angular project. So what they forgot to mention in their simple **Getting Started** documentation is that you need to **import the styles**:

```
// .angular-cli.json
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh.css"
],
```

So I would suggest figuring out where to import the styles in your **react** app.

[image]

See my sample Angular [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/alobban/Ag-Grid-Sample)

Comment: to be fair, that is mentioned in the getting started->angular cli section, as its specific to angular cli

Comment: I see that now. But there are still issues with the flow or lack of documentation like when it comes to overriding themes.